# Android Room. Which method of insertion will be faster?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-insert, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am using Room as an abstraction layer over SQLite. After reading this [page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Insert) I found out that we can insert multiple objects at the same time. Currently I use a For loop to insert objects, i.e one object in each For loop iteration. The two ways of inserting that I know of currently are:

1. Using a For loop and inserting each object one at a time

   `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
   public void addActivity(Person person);`
2. Inserting an array or a list of objects.

   `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
   public void insertUsers(Person ... people);`

When I was coding the insertion of objects, I did not know of the second way of insertion. Now I want to know if there is any noticeable difference in speeds between the two ways so that I can change my code to increase performance of my app.

Comment: You can easily test it by inserting 10k items in the database with each methods and time it. I think batch insertion would be more performant

Comment: I ran the test on a set of 12k items, for-looping it took 55 seconds to save, and using the prepared statement method saved everything in 600ms. I see no reason not to use the 2nd method.

Comment: @BenoitDuffez Hey man , thanks for your effort. Its an interesting observation. Please consider adding this comment as answer so that others can see it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As requested by OP in a comment of their question, here's (for the sake of clarity, as an answer) what I did to check the performance:

Before, inserting objects one by one:

```
@Dao
abstract class MyDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    abstract fun insert(items: MyObject): Long
    // ...
}
```

Syncing code:

```
val response = backend.downloadItems() // download from server
val items = response.getData() // this is a List<MyObject>
if (items != null) {
    for (i in items) {
        myDao.persist(s)
    }
}
```

This took a minute on a Huawei P10+.

I changed this to:

```
@Dao
abstract class MyDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    abstract fun insert(items: Iterable<MyObject>)
    // ...
}
```

Syncing code:

```
val response = backend.downloadItems() // download from server
val items = response.getData() // this is a List<MyObject>
response.getData()?.let { myDao.insert(it) }
```

This took less than a second.

The point here is to use specifically the `Iterable<>` version of the DAO `@Insert` method, which as said by @iDemigod, uses the `Iterable<>` version of the `EntityInsertionAdapter`.

The body of said function is in @iDemigod's answer, and it uses a single prepared statement for all the insertions.

Parsing the SQL into a statement is expensive, and using a statement creates a transaction for the whole insert batch, which can help solve other issues (I had an observable `LiveData<>` on the database, which was notified 12k times during the insert... performance was *awful*).

Comment: This is the correct answer , my calculations also had the same conclusion.

Comment: I have 10300 Objects that I load from a json file and insert them into room. With this change the insert went from 55 seconds to 3 seconds. Exactly what I needed. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood Room generated classes are using `EntityInsertionAdapter` for this particular situation. And there is two methods, we need to check:

1. This one is used for inserting a single entity

   ```
    public final long insertAndReturnId(T entity) {
       final SupportSQLiteStatement stmt = acquire();
       try {
           bind(stmt, entity);
           return stmt.executeInsert();
       } finally {
           release(stmt);
       }
   }
   ```
2. While this one is used to insert an array of entities

   ```
   public final void insert(Iterable<T> entities) {
       final SupportSQLiteStatement stmt = acquire();
       try {
           for (T entity : entities) {
               bind(stmt, entity);
               stmt.executeInsert();
           }
       } finally {
           release(stmt);
       }
   }
   ```

AS you can see the internals are pretty much the same as yours - `stmt.executeInsert();` is called once or in the loop. The only performance change using the `insertUsers` method I can think of is the change notification, which will happen only once, when all the users will be inserted. But if you're already doing you insertion in the loop wrapped with `@Transaction` then there would be no change.

Comment: Is there any performance gain from only calling the acquire() once?

Comment: Yes, cause internally it calls `mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase().compileStatement(sql);` every time on `acquire()`. I'm not sure will it be significant, since it's only a transformation of an sql statement from `String` to `SupportSQLiteStatement` object. But if the performance is a priority, it will definitely improve the whole situation :)

Comment: Yeah so i tried insertion by both methods and found that insertion by arrays is 10 times faster.